# curve-fit for 3 data sets with one shared parameter

Tags: python, excel, curve-fitting

I have an excel file with different sheets(samples). I need the 2nd column (time) and 5th column (Moisture mass) of each sheet (Sample). Using `curve_fit` I want to optimize 3 parameters; one is a shared value(beta) between the 3 samples. But I am facing some difficulties.
I tried to import each sheet separately and run for each sample. and put the Beta as a shared parameter:

```
def sum_4_30_2(N, t2, B, D2):
    z = 0
    for n in np.arange(N + 1):
        don1pi2= ((2 * n+1) * np.pi)**2
        #inside_expo = (-D*t) * (don1pi2) / (4 * (l**2))
        Expo_4_30 = np.exp((-D2 * t2 * (don1pi2)) / (4 * (l_2**2)))
        Makhraj_4_30 = ((don1pi2) * (1 - (don1pi2) * D2 / (4 * B * (l_2**2))))
        z = z + ((8 * Expo_4_30) / Makhraj_4_30)
    return z


def Mt_4_30_2(t2, B, D2, C02):
    turns = 100
    mt_2l_c0 = 1 - (np.exp(-B * t2) * np.sqrt(D2 / (B * (l_2**2))) * np.tan(np.sqrt((B * (l_2**2)) / D2))) - sum_4_30_2(turns, t2, B, D2)
    mt_calc = mt_2l_c0 * ha_2 * C02
    return mt_calc

t2 = time_RH20_2

def predict_2(t2,B,D2,C02):
    smt = []    
    for temp in t2:
        smt.append(Mt_4_30_2(temp, B, D2, C02))
    return smt


def sum_4_30_3(N, t3, B, D3):
    z = 0
    for n in np.arange(N + 1):
        don1pi2 = ((2 * n + 1) * np.pi)**2
        Expo_4_30 = np.exp((-D3 * t3 * (don1pi2)) / (4 * (l_3**2)))
        Makhraj_4_30 = ((don1pi2) * (1 - (don1pi2) * D3 / (4 * B * (l_3**2))))
        z = z + ((8 * Expo_4_30) / Makhraj_4_30)
    return z

def Mt_4_30_3(t3, B, D3, C03):
    turns = 100
    mt_2l_c0 = 1 -(np.exp(-B * t3) * np.sqrt(D3 / (B * (l_3**2))) * np.tan(np.sqrt((B * (l_3**2)) / D3)))- sum_4_30_3(turns, t3, B, D3)
    mt_calc = mt_2l_c0 * ha_3 * C03
    return mt_calc


t3 = time_RH20_3

def predict_3(t3,B,D3,C03):
    smt = []    
    for temp in t3:
        smt.append(Mt_4_30_3(temp, B, D3, C03))
    return smt


def sum_4_30_4(N, t4, B, D4):
    z = 0
    for n in np.arange(N + 1):
        don1pi2= ((2 * n + 1) * np.pi)**2
        Expo_4_30 = np.exp((-D4 * t4 * (don1pi2)) / (4 * (l_4**2)))
        Makhraj_4_30 = ((don1pi2) * (1 - (don1pi2) * D4/(4 * B * (l_4**2))))
        z = z + (( 8 * Expo_4_30) / Makhraj_4_30)
    return z


def Mt_4_30_4(t4, B, D4, C04):
    turns = 100
    mt_2l_c0 = 1 - (np.exp(-B * t4) * np.sqrt(D4 / (B * (l_4**2))) * np.tan(np.sqrt((B * (l_4**2)) / D4))) - sum_4_30_4(turns, t4, B, D4)
    mt_calc = mt_2l_c0 * ha_4 * C04
    return mt_calc


t4 = time_RH20_4

def predict_4(t4, B, D4, C04):
    smt = []    
    for temp in t4:
        smt.append(Mt_4_30_4(temp, B, D4, C04))
    return smt



time = [t2, t3, t4]
Mt=[Mt_RH20_2, Mt_RH20_3, Mt_RH20_4]

def func_3(t,B,D2,D3,D4,C02,C03,C04):
    my=[]
    for t in time:
        if t == t2:
            return predict_2(t2, B, D2, C02)
        if t == t3:
            return predict_3(t3, B, D3, C03)
        if t == t4:
            return predict_4(t4, B, D4, C04 )
        raise Exception('Data outside fitting range')


from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

g = [0.2, 7.53e-6, 7.53e-6, 7.53e-6, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045]

bnds = ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[np.inf, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ])
c,cov = curve_fit(func_3, time, Mt, g, bounds=bnds )
```

for this one it gives me the error of "setting an array element with a sequence"

I also tried to import the excel sheet with pandas and extracted columns 2 & 5  as an ordered dictionary but I  can not call each column to a new list of values as time or moisture mass.  I don't know how to do the for loop that it gets from each sheet the value of column 2 and column 5 and run with the formula.

Comment: Consider concatenating the data together, using separate values for the first two parameters, and making beta in fact shared.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Here a few tips. Try to provide a minimal running working example. i.e. show all imports etc. If code is not essential to solve your problem, drop it, try to boil it down. Provide at least generic data for testing. As it is difficult to give an Excel sheet, add some code to produce  data. If on top you have difficulties to import the data from Excel, post this as a second question, although I guess this is answered here already. The easier you make it to actually run your code and the more precise your question the more likely to get a ( or several ) good answers. Cheers

Comment: Concerning Excel, the easiest way is probably to export as CSV fromExcel and use `numpy.loadtxt()` to import it to python